# Making a simple bbcode function, some issues with linebreaks inside tags

Tags: php

I use the following simple code to make posts safe for output and formatting.

It works good but using [list] adds linebreaks where I dont want them:

```
function tohtml($text, $charset = 'utf-8') {

$text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, $charset);

$basic_bbcode = array('[b]', '[/b]',
                      '[i]', '[/i]',
                      '[u]', '[/u]',
                      '[s]', '[/s]',
                      '[list]', '[/list]',
                      '[*]', '');

$basic_html = array('<b>', '</b>',
                    '<i>', '</i>',
                    '<u>', '</u>',
                    '<s>', '</s>', 
                    '<ul>', '</ul>', 
                    '<li>', '</li>');
$text = str_replace($basic_bbcode, $basic_html, $text);
return str_replace(array('\\r\\n','\r\\n','r\\n','\r\n', '\n', '\r'), '<br />', nl2br($text));
```

For example:

```
This is a list
[list]
[*]List item 1
[*]List item 2
[/list]
```

In source gives:

```
This is a list<br>
<ul><br>
<li>List item 1<br></li>
<li>List item 2<br></li>
</ul>
```

Why would you want a `<br>` inside a `<li>`?

Can I somehow remove every `<br>` that occurs inside `<ul>`?

Comment: Notice that you have `<br/>` after your UL also. Its all being cause by this line, `str_replace(array('\\r\\n','\r\\n','r\\n','\r\n', '\n', '\r'), '<br />', nl2br($text));` which replaces *ALL* newlines with a BR.

Answer (score 1):

If they always come as `<br></li>` then you can easily do an other str_replace of `<br></li>` with `</li>`.

Edit: Or maybe something like this:

```
$newlines = array('<br></li>', '<br /></li>', '<br/></li>');
$str = str_ireplace($newlines, "</li>", $str);
```